# Stumpy: Option to get plain distance rather than z-normalized version

Tags: python, numpy, stumpy

I am carrying out a task where it would be more favourable to compute a regular distance than a z-normalized distance which [stumpy.stump](https://stumpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#stumpy.stump) computes. Is there any way of doing this with this stumpy?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in fact this is already available in `stumpy`. All non-normalized Euclidean distance (i.e., without z-normalization) functions are prefaced with some variation of `aamp` (based on this [research paper][1]). Additionally, the full STUMPY API is [here][2].

For non-normalized Euclidean distance, simply replace your `stumpy.stump` function call with:

```
import stumpy

mp = stumpy.aamp(T, m=50)
```

Finally, for faster responses to your STUMPY questions, I strongly recommend that you post them directly to the [STUMPY Github issues](https://github.com/TDAmeritrade/stumpy/issues/new/choose) since it will reach the developer(s) a lot faster and the community is super helpful!

**Update**

As of STUMPY v1.8.0, we've simplified our API and you can now set the `normalize=False` flag when you want non-normalized distances (i.e., without z-normalization):

```
import stumpy

mp = stumpy.stump(T, m=50, normalize=False)  # Gives the same output as above
```